# Possible that new messages pop-up out of the app?

Tags: android

There is an app that displays news from the RSS feed. What should I implement to have new news popup when the application is not active? Popup directly on the screen no matter which app is running.
I would not like Toast-like message, but rather a real popup with images and text. Is this possible?

Is `AlarmManager` used for this or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dialogs are only possible when your application context is active. So it would not help. Toast could be quite boring for users. Wouldn't you prefer to use notification just to notify new news items are available.

If you really them to be displayed when your app is "not running". I would recommend to provide a desktop widget to your users.

Regards, 
 Stéphane

Comment: Toast can be good if you customize http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

Comment: Thank you both for the info. Can a toast be used when the app is not active? What should I implement in order to activate a toast?

Comment: How can I make `toast` appear let's say on Monday at 15:30 p.m. displaying data from the app? App will not be activated in that time. What should I create to activate the `Toast` at that time?

Comment: You should create a service and create a toast from this service.